# Trigger Step Function in another AWS account using AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a program in AWS Account A whose goal is, when run, calls the startExecution command from AWSStepFunctions SDK (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/stepfunctions/AWSStepFunctions.html) for a Step Function in another account, AWS Account B. However, I am running into permission issues. Would it work to add a Role in Account B that has the following:

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
               "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[Account A ID]:root"
           },
           "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
       }
   ]
}
```

then attach the following policy to it:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Action": [
               "states:StartExecution",
           ],
           "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:states:*:[Account A ID]:activity:*",
              "arn:aws:states:*:[Account A ID]:stateMachine:*",
              "arn:aws:states:*:[Account A ID]:execution:*",
           ],
           "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Am I missing anything out? I'm still running into issues with permissions being denied. Do I need to assume this role in Account A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step Functions just added support for Cross Account services integrations on November 18th. It works by allowing you to assume a different role at the Task level where that role can be in another account.

This blog post will help you get started: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-cross-account-access-capabilities-for-aws-step-functions/